# Javascript change push input to click link (OpenCart Filters)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, opencart

In the Opencart filters I would like to change the Input Box Push to a click link;

**Here is what I have at the minute;**

```
<?php foreach($filter_groups as $filter_group){ ?>
<div>
 <ul>
  <li><span id="filter-group<?php echo $filter_group['filter_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter_group['name']; ?></span> 
   <ul>
   <?php foreach($filter_group['filter'] as $filter){ ?>
   <?php if(in_array($filter['filter_id'], $filter_category)){ ?>
    <li>
     <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" class="item" id="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
     <label for="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></label>
    </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li> 
     <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" class="item" id="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" />
     <label for="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></label>
    </li>
   <?php } ?>
   <?php } ?>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').live('change', function(){
   filter = [];
   $('input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked').each(function(element) {
    filter.push(this.value);
   });
   location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');
  });
 });
//--></script>
```

**I am guessing the HTML will change to something like this;**

```
<?php foreach($filter_groups as $filter_group){ ?>
<div>
 <ul>
  <li><span id="filter-group<?php echo $filter_group['filter_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter_group['name']; ?></span> 
   <ul>
   <?php foreach($filter_group['filter'] as $filter){ ?>
   <?php if(in_array($filter['filter_id'], $filter_category)){ ?>
    <li class="selected">
     <a href="#" class="item" id="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li>
     <a href="#" class="item" id="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></a>
    </li>
   <?php } ?>
   <?php } ?>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I just have no idea how to approaching changing to so it submits an onclick location change that preserves the existing filters.  Are you able to assist me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct, the new HTML should work. To make it simpler (without need of JavaScript) You may fill in the `href` attribute to this dynamic value:

```
<a href="<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></a>
```

(no need of `id` attribute). Now on click the URL is directly triggered changing the filter to new `filter_id`.

Keep in mind that the default approach let's the user to check more than one filter value however with Your approach only one filter value could be selected at a time.

It might be also usefull to display the currently selected filter only as a text node so that it is not clickable, e.g. like this:

```
<?php if(in_array($filter['filter_id'], $filter_category)){ ?>
    <li class="selected">
        <span><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></span>
    </li>
<?php } else { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yer I look at doing it like that, the problem is it replaces the entire filter rather than remembering anything that is already selected.

Comment: That's what I have written in my answer. If You want to `onclick` just add this new value to the current filters, You'd have to implement this logic in PHP part with storing the filters into the session. And in this concrete case You would have to also add a new link *Reset filter* for the user to be able to actually - **reset the filter** ;-) Honestly I do not understand why *trying to build a wheel from pine wood when somebody gave You the exact wheel from oak wood*...

Comment: Thank you again for your help, if I am right with my interpretation of the Javascript code, there is a JavaScript Array, which adds and removes items from the array on the check box version.  I would like for this to remain for the onclick hyperlink version.  I realise I would have to add a reset filters button.

What I am confused about is why you would question when you cannot see or know the implementation. How do I populate the hyperlink with the existing filters appending the new?